# Read data from text table

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, beautifulsoup

I have a table like this:

```
protocol        packets                bytes                 bytes/pkt
------------------------------------------------------------------------
 total         78913220 (100.00%)      47623614577 (100.00%)    603.49
 ip            76930821 ( 97.49%)      45706321977 ( 95.97%)    594.12
  tcp          45432316 ( 57.57%)      38990240707 ( 81.87%)    858.20
```

Actually, you can find some example in [WIDE MAWI WorkingGroup](http://mawi.wide.ad.jp/mawi/ditl/ditl2017/201704120145.html).
I got data with a simple Python code and then I wanna to store each item in some struct like `dict`.

For example:

> It's not a practical code! It's a semi code just for example of that I need.

```
import httplib2
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup, SoupStrainer
import pandas as pd

http = httplib2.Http()

status, response = http.request('http://mawi.wide.ad.jp/mawi/ditl/ditl2017/201704131545.html')

for item in BeautifulSoup(response, parseOnlyThese=SoupStrainer('pre')):
    res = item.text

pd.read_somefunction_to_read_string(res)
if pd['protocol']['ip'] > .09 * pd['protocol']['total']
    do_something
```

Expected Output:

```
 [
     {'protocol' : 'total', 'packet' : 78913220, 'bytes' : 47623614577},
     {'protocol' : 'ip', 'packet' : 76930821, 'bytes' : 45706321977}
 ]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly response can be splitted into rows by the newline character. Then for every row: `protocol`, `packet` and `bytes` fields can be extracted using regex. Then append them a list of dict (`lst_dict`). Lastly convert the `lst_dict` to a pandas DataFrame.

```
import httplib2
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup, SoupStrainer
import pandas as pd
import re

lst_dict = []
http = httplib2.Http()

status, response = http.request('http://mawi.wide.ad.jp/mawi/ditl/ditl2017/201704131545.html')


res = BeautifulSoup(response, parseOnlyThese=SoupStrainer('pre'))
items = res.text.split("\n")
for item in items[2:]:
    item = item.strip()
    protocol = re.search('(\w+)\s.*', item).group(1)
    packet = re.search('\w+\s*(\w+)\s.*', item).group(1)
    byts = re.search('\w+\s*\w+\s\(.*\)\s+(\w+)\s.*', item).group(1)
    dict = {'protocol': protocol, 'packet': packet, 'bytes': byts}
    lst_dict.append(dict)

df = pd.DataFrame(lst_dict)
print df
```

Answer (score 1):

I took a stab at fetching and parsing the data into a list of dict:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, SoupStrainer

r = requests.get('http://mawi.wide.ad.jp/mawi/ditl/ditl2017/201704120145.html')

pre = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "html.parser", parse_only=SoupStrainer('pre'))
entries = pre.text.split("\n")
keys = list(filter(None, entries.pop(0).strip().split("\t")))
entries.pop(0)

rows = []
for entry in entries:
    row = list(filter(None, entry.strip().split("   ")))
    if (len(row)):
        result = {};
        result[keys[0]] = row[0]
        result[keys[1]] = row[1]
        result[keys[2]] = row[2]
        rows.append(result)

print(rows)
```

*(not used pandas, so will leave the rest to you)*

Comment: I do it with something like this but I want to do it with pandas :)